# Issue with TurboPower Async Professional installation on Delphi-XE7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, serial-communication, turbopower

I want to make a Delphi program that can connect to my Arduino via usb(Serial communication), I know i have to use TpaPro (TurboPower Async Professional) for this but i don't know how to install it on Delphi-xe7.

I installed the setup (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpapro/). I added the source directory from TpaPro to the libraries but I still can't see any funtions of tpapro in the tool palette.
I already read the `Readme.txt` but i don't understand the install instructions.

Does anyone know how i can get TpaPro working for Delphi-XE7?

These are the install instructions i don't understand step 4 and 5:

1. Unzip the release files into a directory (e.g., d:\apro).
2. Start Delphi or C++Builder.
3. Add the source subdirectory (e.g., d:\apro\source) to the IDE's
    library path.
4. Open & compile the runtime package specific to the IDE being
    used.
5. Open & install the designtime package specific to the IDE being
    used. The IDE should notify you the components have been
    installed.

Comment: I would start with [`this blog post`](http://blog.kassebaum.eu/?p=379).

Comment: @TLama I found a new version of the project via the blog, but i don't understand 1 thing. I have to install a "designtime package" but where can i find this?

Comment: @TLama I forgot to say that the newest version is on github: https://github.com/TurboPack/AsyncPro

Comment: Ah, ok. So, you open the `\packages\Delphi\Delphi.groupproj` project group and in the Project Manager  you should see two projects. You right click the first one in the tree, AsyncProDR.bpl (that R at the end means runtime) and select From Here | Build All From Here menu item. Both projects will be build. Then you right click the second one, AsyncProDD.bpl (that D at the end means design-time) and select Install menu item. That will install design time package.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer thanks to Tlama.

You open the \packages\Delphi\Delphi.groupproj project group and in the Project Manager you should see two projects. You right click the first one in the tree, AsyncProDR.bpl (that R at the end means runtime) and select From Here | Build All From Here menu item. Both projects will be build. Then you right click the second one, AsyncProDD.bpl (that D at the end means design-time) and select Install menu item. That will install design time package.

Comment: You should have left a comment to TLama for him to put it as an answer ;)